# Listview not refreshing when back to activity

Tags: android, listview

I have defined an Adapter class inside an Activity to populate a listView.

```
   public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter         //has a class viewholder which holds
    {
        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView textName;
            ImageView imageView;
        }

        public List<ListaSalones> parkingList;

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<ListaSalones> arraylist;

        private MyAppAdapter(List<ListaSalones> apps, Context context) {
            this.parkingList = apps;
            this.context = context;
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ListaSalones>();
            arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return parkingList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
        {

            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);

                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // here setting up names and images







            viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).getNombre() );


            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

And this is the way I am calling the adapter:

```
...
if (success == false) {
                } else {
                    try {
                        myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemArrayList, SalonesActivity.this);
                        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

                        listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }

                }

...
```

My issue is that when going back to the activity, the listView doesn't refresh itself and the items are shown twice.
I have tried putting this at onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But it doesn't work and the listView is showing all items twice.

Comment: Please provide information on where do you call your 2nd block of code (onViewCreated?)

Comment: @ror, no, it is executed at OnPostExecute method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to if you put this code in `onResume()` first always check if `myAppAdapter!=null` and then do the check, perhaps the `Adapter` is null and then the app will crash.

Second, what I'm used to do is, if I want to know the changes from one activity to another, in `onResume()` I call the `populateList()` method or whatever you call it again, so items can be filled again with new data.

So it would look like :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   myAsyncTaskExecutor().execute(); //Or whatever is it
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this code:   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(myAppAdapter == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "adapter null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SalonesActivity.SyncDataSesiones orderDataSesiones = new SalonesActivity.SyncDataSesiones();
            orderDataSesiones.execute("");
        }
    }

Comment: So? What's the output

Comment: the app is not crashing but listView shows all items duplicated

Comment: But how do you know the list? where you send this list? From where you get the list to populate the data?

Comment: it is called from a remote mysql database

Comment: You want to clear this list before making the call again : `itemArrayList.clear()`